# what is the simplest way to call a java method on a button click in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, methods, radio-button, click

I have some Java classes that have methods in them and when I click some of my buttons in jsp page a method should be called in order to do some operations. I tried servlets, I tried making an object and I don't know what to do anymore...Nothing works. Please help me !! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Either submit form to make synchronous request to server to perform the action you want
2. Or you can invoke an ajax call for asynchronous call.